# Get count on associated in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4, cakephp-model

I'm using `CakePHP 3.4+`

I have three tables

1. table_a
2. table_b
3. table_status

and association are

1. `table_a` hasMany `table_b` *(`table_b` contain foreign key `table_a_id`)*
2. `table_b` belongsTo `table_status` *(`table_b` contain foreign key `table_status_id`)*

Now, I'm fetching records from `table_a` containing `table_b` and `table_status`

```
$records = $this->TableA->find()
    ->where([
        'TableA.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
        'TableA.deleted' => false,
    ])
    ->contain([
        'TableB.TableStatus',
    ]);
```

in the `template` file, I'm looping over `$records`

```
<tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Record count</td>
</tr>
<?php foreach($records as $record): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $record->title ?></td>
        <td><?= count($record->table_b) ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

which output as

```
+---------+--------------+
| Title   | Record Count |
+---------+--------------+
| T1      | 5            |
+---------+--------------+
| T2      | 8            |
+---------+--------------+
```

`table_status` has three fields `failed`, `pending`, `complete`.

I want to display `Record Count` column in format

```
<count_failed>/<count_pending>/<count_complete>
eg., 1/4/3       ## where 1 => count_failed, 4 => count_pending, 3 => count_complete
```

**How to include `count AS` in the query to create three variables of count based on associated model for each record?**

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#aggregates-group-and-having

Comment: "table_status has three fields"... are there three columns? What data type are them?